Clangd LSP in Neovim using .clangd file not working
I am trying to get clangd LSP to work in Neovim using a .clangd file for a library. I am creating the compile_commands.json file using cmake in the build folder. The full folder structure is as follows
root
  - build/
  - include/subfolder/header1.hpp
  - src/subfolder/source1.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - .clangd

and the content of the .clangd file is
CompileFlags:
  CompilationDatabase: build/

Unfortunately, LSP does not recognize
#include<subfolder/header1.hpp>

in source1.cpp.
Creating a symbolic link to compile_commands.json in the root folder does work. However, I am keen to get the .clangd file solution working as it is a bit more robust across machines.

This setup sounds like it should work. Can you post clangd logs for further diagnosis?
